# Can I manage TLS version negotiation of OpenSSL 1.0+ by ENV variable or config? Want force exactly TLSv1

Tags: openssl, shopify

Can I force SSLv3 or TLSv1 for any program using OpenSSL by setting ENV variable or `openssl.cnf` config file? I found that my OpenSSL 1.0.1c version start negotiating TLSv1.2 at the 1st and that makes me problem connecting to specific API (namely Shopify API). It fails with `SSL protocol error`.

That problem is common for any SW linked against my OpenSSL 1.0.1c, versions <1.0 works well, in my case OSX bundled 0.9.8r. Also found Ubuntu's 1.0.1c is OK... that's overwhelming.

A test:

```
curl https://ApiKey:Passwd@shop.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json
```

Fails exactly after 1min. with `Unknown SSL protocol error`.

```
curl -1 https://ApiKey:Passwd@shop.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json
```

Passes immediately OK.

So then default negotiation doesn't work OK. I need to force SSLv3 or TLSv1 (not TLSv1.1+), but I'm not going to rewrite every library or util.

I'm going to use Python and presently I can communicate just using PyCURL and forcing SSLv3 or TLSv1. I can't use original ShopifyAPI library cause of that SSL default negotiation issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the connection needs to use --sslv3 to work correctly, see this other SO post for more detail [Can I change a date on shopify blog using api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221455/can-i-change-a-date-on-shopify-blog-using-api)

Comment: Yes... as I said SSLv3 and TLSv1 works fine, but TLSv1.1+ does not. Need to change OpenSSL default connection negotiation without altering code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. You have to pass the option to the curl calls or make a utility which will do it for you.